# Str object has no attribute occurrences

Tags: python, readfile, insertion-sort

I am working on a program that takes a list of names and returns the top twenty occurrences of names, regardless of genders.

I have a bit of a hard time understanding what I am doing wrong because I'm trying to use insertion_sort and it is not working.

Here is the code.

```
        class babyName():
            __slots__ = ("name" , "gender" , "occurrences")

            def __init__(self, name, gender, occurrences):
                self.name = name
                self.gender = gender
                self.occurrences = occurrences

            def __str__(self):
                return self.name + "," + self.gender + "," + self.occurrences

        def mkEntry(name, gender, occurrences):
            entry = babyName(name, gender, occurrences)

            return entry

        def readFile(year):
           lst = []
           lst2 = []
           topm = 20
           topf = 20
           yob = ("yob" + str(year) + ".txt")
           for line in open("names/" + yob ):     
               line = line.split(",")
               if line[1] == "F":
                   if topf > 0:
                       entry = mkEntry(line[0], line[1], line[2])
                       lst.append(entry)
                       topf -= 1
               elif line[1] == "M":
                   if topm > 0:
                       entry = mkEntry(line[0], line[1], line[2])
                       lst2.append(entry)
                       topm -= 1
            mergedlist = lst + lst2

            return mergedlist

        def insertion_sort(lst):
            for i in range(1, len(lst)):
                h = i - 1
                val = lst[i].occurrences
                val2 = lst[i-1].occurrences
                while (h >= 0) and (val2 > val):
                    lst[h+1] = lst[h]
                    h = h - 1
                lst[h+1] = val

       def main():
           year = input("Enter the year of birth:")
           file = readFile(year)
           insertion_sort(file)
           for x in file:
               print(x)

       main()
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
lst[h+1] = val # val isn't a babyName instance
```

should probably be

```
lst[h+1] = lst[i]
```

Comment: Great, made it actually run but now it keeps returning a list with the same value over and over....

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm. shouldn't there be a placeholder for the thing that gets moved/inserted?

```
def insertion_sort(lst):
    for i in range(1, len(lst)):
        # placeholder for the item being moved
        tmp = lst[i]
        h = i - 1
        val = lst[i].occurrences
        val2 = lst[i-1].occurrences
        while (h >= 0) and (val2 > val):
            lst[h+1] = lst[h]
            h = h - 1
        lst[h+1] = tmp
```

You might want to look at the pseudocode in the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) article.